# How to identify non-identical values being aggregated with COUNT()?

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregates

I have a table containing three columns: city ID, language code and city:

```
city_id | language_code | city
----------------------------------
1       | en            | London
1       | es            | Londres
1       | pt            | Londres
2       | de            | Köln
2       | en            | Cologne
3       | it            | Cologne
```

In some foreign languages cities can be spelled the same way, e.g. the Spanish and Portuguese name for London is `Londres`.

But there are cases where the same name can refer to completely different locations, e.g. `Cologne` is an English name for the German city of Köln but there's also a town of the same name in Italy.

I would like to be able to detect cities that have more than one entry in the table but only those that are linked to different `city_id` values. In my case this would be `Cologne` but not `Londres` as both `es` and `pt` language versions point to the same `city_id`.

I thought this would be a fairly easy thing to do but I haven't been able to get the results in a single query. Instead, I am deduping the results first and then aggregating them:

```sql
WITH deduped_cities AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT city, city_id
  FROM cities
  ORDER BY city
)
SELECT city, COUNT(city_id) AS total
FROM deduped_cities
GROUP BY city
HAVING COUNT(city_id) > 1;
```

This gives me the expected result:

```
city    | total
----------------
Cologne | 2
```

I was just wondering if it is possible to achieve the same effect with a single SELECT statement.

[DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=4e8189675f34b4bd901ac04d02c3733f)

Comment: Currently the "Suggested edit queue is full". Would have suggested to correct the "Koln" vs "Köln" typo. Great question, by the way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have basically just one `SELECT`, but you can use `DISTINCT`'  with the `COUNT`

```
SELECT city, COUNT(city_id) AS total
FROM cities
GROUP BY city
HAVING COUNT( DISTINCT city_id) > 1;
```

See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=d9d8563c22d3fe9c6d6d362c8c1ee7eb)

Comment: Thank your very much for your prompt response and an updated Fiddle @nbk - very helpful and it's interesting to see you are using `DISTINCT` only in the `HAVING` clause and not in `SELECT` (like in the @Hambone's answer).

Comment: the select distinct is not necessary, as you filter already everything ouf of the rows, that don't fit, you see in the response that it gives all the rows, even when you have 3 or 4 of them and not only 2, so a Distinct will not change anything

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can just do the distinct within the aggregate and the having clause:

```
select city, count (distinct city_id)
from cities
group by city
having count (distinct city_id) > 1
```

Comment: Great answer, thank you, @Hambone!